# Show and Hide div not working properly (laravel5.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am working with laravel 5.3
I have to show and hide div its working fine but problem is that i want if the value for hidden div was set it should be opens on edit page and the main thing is that it should also work on same behavior for show and hide as it was on create page.

I am passing a veritable **$attributes** from my edit page as

I want if value for $attribute is set the hidden div should be open with that values. i was able to do this but problem is that its also should be close as it was at create page.

Here is My code **Script**

```
<script>
       $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

     $('#dropDown').change(function () 
    {
        $(this).find("option").each(function () {
            $('#' + this.value).hide();
        });
        $('#' + this.value).show();
    });
</script>
```

**view**

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3">
Type
</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <select name="type" id="dropDown">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1" {{ (isset($tests->type) && $tests->type == 1) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                Old Student
            </option>
            <option value="2" {{ (isset($tests->type) && $tests->type == 2) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                Crrunt Student
            </option>
    </select>
</div>
 </div>

<div id="2" class="drop-down-show-hide">
<div class="form-group">
    <label col-md-3">Name
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input-icon right">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{isset($attributes->name) ? $attributes->$name : '' }}" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Its fine for me on create page just problem is that if $attribute is set the hidden dive which is 2nd one should be open on edit but as i click on any other drop down its also should hide as it was able to show and hide on create page
I use this fiddle to show and hide div [Show hide Div](http://jsfiddle.net/CDyZf/136/)

Comment: ok please remove your comment i will @mwallisch

Answer (score -1):

I am still not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but here is something that might be useful **that works if you have your javascript code within your view**. You can use blade directives embedded in your javascript to help setting the initial state of your result-div.

```
<script>
   // initialize the result div, if values are present show, otherwise hide
   @if(!isset($attributes))
       theDiv.hide();
   @endif

   // ... rest of your js logic
</script>
```